# Finding derivative of inverse function.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, inverse-function

I was trying the below question and am unable to integrate the function. I tried different substitutions but get stuck in between.

> Let $f(x)=\displaystyle\int_2^x\frac{1}{1+t^4}\,dt$ and $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. Find $\frac{d}{dx}(g(x))$ at x=0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I need to solve it on paper.

Comment: This is just an application of the inverse function theorem which states that if $f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of a point $a$ with nonzero derivative at $a$ then $$\left.\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}\right|_{f(a)} = \frac{1}{f'(a)}$$

Comment: If I may comment on your notation: $\frac{d}{dx}(g(0)) = 0$ because $g(0)$ is a constant: you're differentiating $g(0)$ to $x$. I assume what you want is actually $\frac{dg}{dx}(0) = g'(0)$, i.e. the derivative of $g$ evaluated in $0$?

Comment: Please check if what you want to evaluate is correctly mentioned in the post. I had edited it based on what was written vaguely.

Comment: I think it should be to find $g'(0)$ as well.

Comment: Yah thanks for the edit. How do I write g'(x) at x=0

Comment: @SteamyRoot already answered that: $g'(0).$

Comment: 0 is not the ans. The ans given is /sqrt{17}

Comment: Are you sure?  I just get $17$.

Comment: Yah that's the ans given in the book. Maybe its printing mistake

Comment: Who said the answer is $0?$ It's $g'(0).$

Comment: Thanks for the help I got the ans

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=f\left( g\right)$, $\frac{dx}{dg}=f'\left( g\right)=\frac{1}{1+g^4}$ so $\frac{dg}{dx}=\left( \frac{dx}{dg}\right)^{-1}=1+g^4$. Solving $f\left( g\right)=0$ gives $g=2$, so at $x=0$ we have $\frac{dg}{dx}=17$.